# Images are showing when I'm viewing the page with live server but when I'm opening the html file in the browser are not showing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made a website in vscode with the live server extension. The images that I added are working in live server but when I'm opening the file separately they are not.

This is how I linked the images

src="/images/winter.png"

Comment: put your code in jsFiddle and share the link, so everybody can see better what you are trying to fix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use relative path src="~/images/winter.png" or src="./images/winter.png"
If you want to open the file separately use from the server:-
src="http:www.domainname.com/images/winter.png"
Please let me know if you have any questions. Thank you